# ConcatMap in haskell without ++

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write the code for Haskell concatmap without using the `++` operator where

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
```

and producing the same result of

```
concatMap f = foldr ((++) . f) []
```

I'm quite new to Haskell and this was just an exercise I found. Actually, I do not even know if this can be done.

Comment: How would you implement `(++)` yourself?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yes, you can do something like that but i wonder if it can be done without it.
```(++)                    :: [a] -> [a] -> [a] ``` 

```[]     ++ ys            =  ys``` 

```(x:xs) ++ ys            =  x : (xs++ys)```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a way that makes the state of the computation explicit:

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
concatMap f = go []
  where
    -- We have b values; use one.
    go (b:bs) as = b : go bs as
    -- No bs left; get some more.
    go [] (a:as) = go (f a) as
    -- Nothing left; we're done.
    go [] [] = []
```

This maintains the current list of `b`s, filling it up whenever it's empty.

Answer (score 4):

This might be cheating, but how about:

```
myConcatMap f s = concat (map f s)
```

The `concat` function uses some sort of `++` in its source code, so that is why you might not like it. You can try to use an alternative `concat` that does list comprehensions, it has a more "from scratch" feeling.

```
myconcat ll = [y | x <- ll, y <- x]
```

Comment: Or, for that matter, `concatMap f xs = [y | x <- xs, y <- f x]`, which I believe is how it's actually defined in the `base` package. But the comprehension has to be translated to something else under the hood.

Comment: I like that, it has a very math-like quality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that `foldr (:)` = `flip (++)`

```
concatMap f = foldr (flip (foldr (:)) . f) []
```

Or pointfree:

```
concatMap = flip foldr [] . (flip (foldr (:)) .)
```